# openapi-generator-maven-plugin and nullable object

Tags: dictionary, openapi, nullable, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I found a problem when generating a nullable object and don't know how to solve it.

- In the example below, the Attribute component has only one languageValues field
- languageValues is a dictionary that can be nullable
- when generating, i get an error: /Attribute.java:[41,40] incompatible types: cannot infer type arguments for java.util.HashMap<>

Technical information:

- openapi: 3.0.1
- openapi-generator-maven-plugin: 6.5.0

openapi.yml

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: content-hub
  description: Syndication content hub
  version: @project.version@
servers:
  - url: http://localhost:8080
    description: localhost
tags:
  - name: Attribute controller
paths:
  /v1/attribute/{id}:
    get:
      tags:
        - Attribute controller
      parameters:
        - name: id
          description: Attribute id
          required: true
          in: path
          schema:
            type: string
          example: "0006776500"
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Success
          content:
            '*/*':
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Attribute'
components:
  schemas:
    Attribute:
      type: object
      properties:
        languageValues:
          nullable: true
          type: object
          additionalProperties:
            type: string
    Error:
      type: object
      properties:
        errors:
          type: array
          items:
            type: object
            properties:
              errorCode:
                type: string
              errorDescription:
                type: string
```

Generated Attribute.java

```
public class Attribute {

  @Valid
  private JsonNullable<Map<String, String>> languageValues = JsonNullable.undefined();

  ...

  public Attribute putLanguageValuesItem(String key, String languageValuesItem) {
    if (this.languageValues == null) {
      this.languageValues = new HashMap<>();
    }
    this.languageValues.put(key, languageValuesItem);
    return this;
  }

   ...
```

for some reason, this method does not use "JsonNullable.of()" when initializing a variable

I have little experience in the open api specification. The only thing I tried was to reproduce the problem in openapi 3.1, but the generator does not support this version yet